# uploading a image but error of undefined index

Tags: php

I have a form in which i have to upload the image by its category and move the selected category image to specific folder but when i submit the form the following error occurs
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: pic in C:\wamp\www\movies poster admin\insertform.php on line 26
the pic is the name of the file but don't know why it did not get the value
I know this is a very basic question but i don't know why this error is coming

```
        $imageprice=$_POST['imageprice'];
        $imagedescription=$_POST['imagedescription'];
        $type=$_POST['category'];

        if ($type="celeb") {
            $uploadDir = 'C:/wamp/www/Movies Poster Site/celeb/'; //Image Upload Folder
            $fileName = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
            $tmpName  = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['pic']['size'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['pic']['type']; 
            $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
            $filename = $fileName;
            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            //$date = date_create();
            //$fileName= date_timestamp_get($date).".".$ext;
            $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
            if (isset($fileName)) {

                # code...

            $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
            }
            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
            }
```

`

```
`$sql="INSERT INTO celeb ". 
        "(image_name,price,description,Type) ".
        "VALUES ".
        "('$filePath','$imageprice','$imagedescription','$type') ";
        mysql_select_db('poster');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connection );
        if(! $retval )
        {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
        echo"   <div class='end'>";
        echo "Data Entered";
        echo"</div>";
        mysql_close($connection);
        }
```

Here is the form

```
<form method="post">
<div class="insertform">

<!--         <input  type="text" placeholder="image.jpg" name="imagename" id="imagename"><br>
 -->

Select Image Category:<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="comic">Comic Posters<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="celeb">Celeb Posters<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="islamic">Islamic Posters<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="tv">TV Posters<br>
<input type="radio" name="category" value="motor">Motor Posters<br />
<input type="radio" name="category" value="sports">Sports Posters<br><br />

Image Name :<br>
<input style="margin-left:10px;" id="uploadImage" required="required"  name="pic" type="file" size="4
                000000" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png" > <br>
  Image Price :<br>
        <input  type="text" placeholder="Rs xxx" name="imageprice" id="price"><br>
Image Description :<br>
        <input  type="text" name="imagedescription" id="description" height="300px"><br /><br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
```

Comment: Add your form below PHP looks fine.

Comment: Tangential, but in your `if` you want `==`, not `=`.

Comment: you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form as one of the paramaters. Else the form will not post the file/image data.

Answer (score -1):

try like this,

```
$fileName = $_FILES['pic']['name'][0];
```